# Can we use the use frontdoor link to redirect to a salesforce record directly by passing parameters?

Tags: session

I am currently able to login inside salesforce using just a session id
https://eu5.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=sessionId

I now want to be able to redirect to a record page by passing 1 additional parameters &retUrl=/0032400000GRVvYAAX

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What's not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works pretty much as you've suggested. Send the users browser to:

> https://eu5.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=*sessionId*&retURL=%2F0032400000GRVvYAAX

Remember to URL encode the forward slash in the retURL parameter.

As Rahul Sharma commented, check the casing of `retURL` as well. The casing needs to match exactly.

Comment: It even works with `&retURL=/0032400000GRVvYAAX`, could be due to fact that retURL is case sensitive!

Comment: @RahulSharma The casing on the ID given does appear to be correct for the `AAX` suffix in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I meant parameter name `retURL` is case-sensitive not the Id or value. So, encoding is good to have but is not a problem in this example.

Comment: @RahulSharma Ah yes, good point!

Comment: Also, outlined in [KA 000193348](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000193348&language=en_US&type=1).